# How can I take an array in google sheets and return it in a different order than the original?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have an array of data that is in a certain order imported from another sheet. In this sheet, i need to filter that data and show it in a different order. The left side of the picture is the data as imported, and the columns on the right (AC:AI)are the order the information needs to change to. I realize I could just write ={U2:U} in column AF and repeat that in all the columns, however I have the feeling that is a clunky way to do this and Ive had similar problems in other places before. Im looking for a way to reorder this array in one cell (probably cell AC2).

[image]

Comment: Can you add more details and your desired output with the link of your dummy sheet on your question? Remove sensitive information, if any

Comment: Did you try `SORT()` function or `QUERY()` with `order` clause.

Comment: Its up to you. You could use a `query in AC2 based on {U2:AA} where U is not null` OR you could have a script `setValues` - either run manually, or time-driven.